# Directory does not exist when initializing Windows 10 host from Linux machine

Tags: linux, windows-10, command-line, samba

I am trying to initialize a program on my Linux machine using a file from my Windows 10 machine. I am using a samba server that is up and running. The command

```
program init -c \\192.168.0.10\Users\user\.program\mainnet\config\ssl\ca
```

returns the result

```
** Directory \\192.168.0.10Usersuser.programmainnetconfigsslca does not exist **
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should mount the share onto some directory first, then access the file with mountpoint/path/to/file (slash but not backslash).

Comment: Does this directory need to be on the host machine, or the machine initializing it?

Comment: the Linux machine (i.e. the client that access the share).

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the backslashes or to put it another way, try this:
program init -c \\192.168.0.10\\Users\\user\\.program\\mainnet\\config\\ssl\\ca